# Disable Community Topics Autosuggestion while asking questions

Tags: community, napili

I am using Salesforce Standard Communities (Napili Template)

I have a requirement to disable Topic auto suggestion while asking question to community (by clicking on 'Ask The Community' button)

Steps to reproduce

1. Click on 'Ask The Community'
2. Type 'what is a zero dollar receipt ?' in subject
3. Type same in description
4. Notice now you have "DOLLAR RECEIPT" in topic automatically

[image]

I tried to hide it through Custom CSS but it still executing in background and added topics to question

Any suggestions ?